# SQL Server Identity primary key vs no Identity performance - Using formula in primary key

Tags: sql-server, performance, primary-key, identity, uniqueidentifier

Are there any differences in performance between `Identity` primary key and normal primary keys?

Actually I want to create a table that may fill with more than 5 million rows. The table should return queries with filter condition over 4 columns in less than half a second.

Since these 4 columns (which are all primary keys from other tables) are all numeric and their range is limited, I decided to mix all 4 columns in primary key.

Column ranges could be for example `col1=500 | col2=500 | col3=900,000 | col4=9,000,000` and the range of `bigint` is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 so if I wanted to mix all 4 columns in a `bigint` primary key it can provide it .

Is there any problem with this solution ?

Comment: Depends on how you determine the ID of new rows for "normal" primary keys. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32597/Performance-Comparison-Identity-x-NewId-x-NewSeque

Comment: What is a "normal" primary key? Is it the same data type? Is it sequential? How is it populated? Your question is like asking "How fast is a Volvo compared to a normal car?"

Comment: yes with the same data type, e.a  bigint with identity and bigint with no indetity .

Comment: I can't imagine there would be much difference as long as it's a clustered index.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have a composite PK on all 4 columns `smallint,smallint,int,int`? Mashing 4 different columns into a single `bigint` violates 1st normal form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your solution are same:

1)A compsite `PK` with 4 columns

2)A `BIGINT` column(regardless of identity or not) that is `PK`

Sql Server mechanism for indexing is same for both:Data will sort and save in a place.you can test both that way with this `Statistics`:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

I tested it and those were same.

Comment: it takes a while for me to test,but right after I test it ,I mark yours as correct answer .

Comment: @Navid you should click on the `Answer CheckBox` for mark az answer

Answer (score 3):

Dipping my toe into some deep waters:

Constraints (such as primary and foreign keys) impact validity more than performance; it's the layout and structure of your underlying indexes that ususally provide more of an impact on how well a given query will perform.  Granted, applying a PRIMARY KEY contraint to a table will construct a UNIQUE index on that table, but that index may or may not be clustered (dependign on how and when it's created).

If the PRIMARY KEY is built as a clustered index on an IDENTITY column, which is monotonically increasing by definition, then your clustered key will have minimal fragmentation resulting from standard INSERT operations; if you build it on the other four columns, and the data is inserted in non-monotonic fashion, then you may see substantial fragmentation build up over time, whcih could lead from perfomance problems.  However, if your data is always going to be inserted in sequential order, this may not be a problem.

You mentioned filtering, but what about joins?